# FileProvider - java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to find configured root that contains

Tags: java, android, kotlin, androidx, android-fileprovider

I am trying to expose a URI using FileProvider, but keep running into this exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to find configured root that contains /data/data/com.example.android.development/cache/images/background.png
```

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<provider
    android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
    android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
    android:exported="false"
    android:grantUriPermissions="true">
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
        android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"/>
</provider>
```

provider_paths.xml:

```
<paths>
    <cache-path name="images" path="images/"/>
</paths>
```

Saving the file:

```
fun cache(context: Context, bitmap: Bitmap, fileName: String) {
    val filePath = File(context.cacheDir, "images")
    val file = File(filePath, fileName)
    try {
        filePath.mkdirs()
        val fos = FileOutputStream(file)
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos)
        fos.close()
    } catch (e: IOException) {
        throw RuntimeException(e)
    }
}
```

Getting the URI:

```
fun getUri(context: Context, fileName: String): Uri {
    val filePath = File(context.cacheDir, "images")
    val file = File(filePath, fileName)
    return FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, "${context.applicationContext.packageName}.provider", file)
}
```

I did some debugging and it seems that the `FileProvider` `getUriForFile(File file)` function first converts the file path `/data/user/0/com.example.android.development/cache/images/background.png` to the canonical file path `/data/data/com.example.android.development/cache/images/background.png`, then tries to match the root path `/storage/emulated/0` with the canonical file path. When it does not find this match, it throws the exception.
I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong to cause this or how to fix this?

Debugging FileProvider.java getUriForFile(File file):

```
@Override
public Uri getUriForFile(File file) { // file: "/data/user/0/com.example.android.development/cache/images/background.png"
    String path; // path: "/data/data/com.example.android.development/cache/images/background.png"
    try {
        path = file.getCanonicalPath();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Failed to resolve canonical path for " + file);
    }

    // Find the most-specific root path
    Map.Entry<String, File> mostSpecific = null;
    for (Map.Entry<String, File> root : mRoots.entrySet()) {
        final String rootPath = root.getValue().getPath(); // rootPath: "/storage/emulated/0"
        if (path.startsWith(rootPath) && (mostSpecific == null // path: "/data/data/com.example.android.development/cache/images/background.png"
                || rootPath.length() > mostSpecific.getValue().getPath().length())) {
            mostSpecific = root; // mostSpecific: null
        }
    }

    if (mostSpecific == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                "Failed to find configured root that contains " + path);
    }

    // Start at first char of path under root
    final String rootPath = mostSpecific.getValue().getPath();
    if (rootPath.endsWith("/")) {
        path = path.substring(rootPath.length());
    } else {
        path = path.substring(rootPath.length() + 1);
    }

    // Encode the tag and path separately
    path = Uri.encode(mostSpecific.getKey()) + '/' + Uri.encode(path, "/");
    return new Uri.Builder().scheme("content")
            .authority(mAuthority).encodedPath(path).build();
}
```

Things I have already tried:

1. Add `<root-path name="root" path="." />` to `<paths>`
2. Try `filesDir` instead of `cacheDir`
3. Run the app on a phone instead of an emulator

Comment: "then tries to match the root path /storage/emulated/0 with the canonical file path" -- that would not match your `provider_paths.xml`. Change `"${context.applicationContext.packageName}.provider"` to `"${BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID}.provider"` and see if you get different results.

Comment: No luck, I get the same result. `context.applicationContext.packageName` and `BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID` both return `com.example.android.development`

Comment: Go into Build > APK Analyzer in Android Studio and analyze your APK. In the tab that you get, go into `res/xml/provider_paths.xml` and see if it matches what you have in the question. I'm wondering if due to multiple modules or libraries or something that you are getting a different `provider_paths` resource than you are expecting.

Comment: Oh, you're right. `provider_paths` in my APK looks like this: `<external-path name="images" path="." />` Do you know how I can fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your project has multiple resources named `res/xml/provider_paths.xml`, and you are winding up with one that is for some other `FileProvider` than yours.

For example, you might have an `app/` module and a `something/` library module that `app/` depends upon. If they both have `res/xml/provider_paths.xml`, then IIRC `app/` "wins", and its resource gets included.

The simplest solution is to rename your resource to be something else (e.g., `res/xml/images_provider_paths.xml`) and update your `<provider>` manifest entry to point to the new name.

Comment: I renamed `provider_paths.xml` to `file_provider_paths.xml`, but now I'm getting this error:
`Attribute meta-data#android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS@resource value=(@xml/provider_paths) from AndroidManifest.xml:19:17-55 is also present at AndroidManifest.xml:26:17-60 value=(@xml/file_provider_paths). Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:resource"' to <meta-data> element at AndroidManifest.xml to override.`

I followed the suggestion and added `tools:replace="android:resource` to `<meta-data>` in my manifest file, but the error persists. Is there something that I'm missing?

Comment: I also tried adding `tools:replace="android:resource` to `<application>` instead, but that resulted in `tools:replace specified at line:10 for attribute android:resource, but no new value specified`

Comment: @syhark: OK, I forgot about that. You appear to be using a library written by someone who did not read [this blog post of mine from 2017](https://commonsware.com/blog/2017/06/27/fileprovider-libraries.html). But, you should be able to pull off the same trick, just in reverse: create a trivial subclass of `FileProvider` and switch your `<provider>` element to point to it. Also, look in the merged manifest for both `FileProvider` `<provider>` elements and make sure that you each have a distinct authority string.